# How to limit number of uploads by user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

relatively new to ruby on rails and I'm creating a simple Uploads model for Paperclip images to be attached and displayed.  I've got that all working well, but I want to limit a current user to upload no more than 6 images at any given time.

In what file and what code would I add this?  It would be quite helpful to know this for any future model I create !

I'm assuming it's quite a small bit of code but I can't see an answer anywhere online... thanks !

my UploadsController (did a simple scaffolding and paperclip setup):

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_upload, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /uploads
      # GET /uploads.json
      def index
        @uploads = Upload.all
      end

      # GET /uploads/1
      # GET /uploads/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /uploads/new
      def new
        @upload = current_user.uploads.build
      end

      # GET /uploads/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /uploads
      # POST /uploads.json
      def create
        @upload = current_user.uploads.build(upload_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @upload.save
            format.html { redirect_to @upload, notice: 'Upload was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @upload }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /uploads/1
      # PATCH/PUT /uploads/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @upload.update(upload_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @upload, notice: 'Upload was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @upload }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /uploads/1
      # DELETE /uploads/1.json
      def destroy
        @upload.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to uploads_url, notice: 'Upload was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_upload
          @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def upload_params
          params.require(:upload).permit(:upload_title, :upload_description, :upload_datecreated, :user_id, :picture, :delete_picture)
        end
    end
```

Upload model:

```
 class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
        has_attached_file :picture, styles: { large: "600x600#", medium: "300x300#", small: "150x150#", thumb: "50x50#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
        validates_attachment_content_type :picture, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

        before_validation { image.clear if @delete_image }

        def delete_picture
          @delete_image ||= false
        end

        def delete_picture=(value)
          @delete_image  = !value.to_i.zero?
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base

  MAX_IMAGES = 6
  validate :maximum_images

  private

  def count_valid_images
    self.user.uploads.count
  end

  def maximum_images
    errors.add(:base, "must have max #{MAX_IMAGES} images") if count_valid_images > MAX_IMAGES
  end


end
```

Comment: Thanks on the quick reply Dennis but that doesn't seem to work for me.  I added exactly as above to my upload model, still lets me attach more than six images with one user.  the name of my Paperclip attachment is 'picture' not 'image', would that matter at all?

Comment: the picture is an attribute to Upload model. Your model User has_many :uploads. are you sure the upload is populate the user_id attribute?, try in console. User.first.uploads.count

Comment: it is weird, when i look at the user attribute for each record in the Upload model, it's a long unintelligible ID # that is different for each record.  However, the user_id is the normal numeric # for that user... does Devise do something weird here?